# Unintuitive type signature in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-signature

I made this (what I thought to be) fairly straightforward code to calculate the third side of a triangle:

```
toRadians :: Int -> Double
toRadians d = let deg = mod d 360
              in deg/180 * pi

lawOfCosines :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Double
lawOfCosines a b gamma = sqrt $ a*a + b*b - 2*a*b*(cos (toRadians gamma))
```

However, when I tried to load it into GHCi, I got the following errors:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( law_of_cosines.hs, interpreted )

law_of_cosines.hs:3:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `(/)', namely `deg'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `deg / 180'
    In the expression: deg / 180 * pi

law_of_cosines.hs:6:26:
    No instance for (Floating Int)
      arising from a use of `sqrt'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
    In the expression: sqrt
    In the expression:
      sqrt $ a * a + b * b - 2 * a * b * (cos (toRadians gamma))
    In an equation for `lawOfCosines':
        lawOfCosines a b gamma
          = sqrt $ a * a + b * b - 2 * a * b * (cos (toRadians gamma))

law_of_cosines.hs:6:57:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Double'
    In the return type of a call of `toRadians'
    In the first argument of `cos', namely `(toRadians gamma)'
    In the second argument of `(*)', namely `(cos (toRadians gamma))'
```

It turns out the fix was to remove my type signatures, upon which it worked fine.

```
toRadians d = let deg = mod d 360
              in deg/180 * pi

lawOfCosines a b gamma = sqrt $ a*a + b*b - 2*a*b*(cos (toRadians gamma))
```

And when I query the type of `toRadians` and `lawOfCosines`:

```
*Main> :t toRadians
toRadians :: (Floating a, Integral a) => a -> a
*Main> :t lawOfCosines
lawOfCosines :: (Floating a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a -> a
*Main>
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? Why the "intuitive" type signatures I had written were in fact incorrect?

Comment: deg is an int mod has type int -> int -> int.  You have to use fromInteger or fromIntegral to convert to a floating point in the first function

Answer (score 11):

The problem is in `toRadians`: `mod` has the type `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, therefore, `deg` has the type `Integral i => i` (so either `Int` or `Integer`).

You then try and use `/` on `deg`, but `/` doesn't take integral numbers (divide integrals with `div`):

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

The solution is to simply use `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`:

```
toRadians :: Int -> Double
toRadians d = let deg = mod d 360
              in (fromIntegral deg)/180 * pi
```

Comment: Yeah, but this definitely isn't a good spot to put the `fromIntegral`. It merely circumvents the problem, which actually lies in the type signature.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Why is the type signature necessarily a problem? OP specified it explicitly, so maybe it's that way for a reason.

Comment: The OP may have a good reason to start with `Int` in their particular program (e.g. the angles are read in from a physical sensor that happens to measure in deg integer), but a general-purpose function such as `lawOfCosines` shouldn't be bothered by such ugly implementation details but keep to the most general reasonable signature (at least unless there's some good special reason to do otherwise, like optimisation).   You wouldn't put all that code in the `IO` monad either, even when this is ultimately the only use case, would you?

Answer (score 5):

Seeing `Floating a` and `Integral a` in a type signature together always sets off my internal alarm bells, as these classes are supposed to be mutually exclusive - at least, there are no standard numeric types that are instances of both classes. GHCi tells me (along with a lot of other stuff):

```
> :info Integral
...
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
> :info Floating
...
instance Floating Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Floating Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

To see why these classes are mutually exclusive, let's have a look at some of the methods in both classes (this is going to be a bit handwavy). `fromInteger` in `Integral` converts an `Integral` number to an `Integer`, without loss of precision. In a way, `Integral` captures the essence of being (a subset of) the mathematical integers.

On the other hand, `Floating` contains methods such as `pi` and `exp`, which have a pronounced 'real number' flavour.

If there were a type that was both `Floating` and `Integral`, you could write `toInteger pi` and have a integer that was equal to 3.14159... - and that's not possible :-)

---

That said, you should change all your type signatures to use `Double` instead of `Int`; after all, not all triangles have integer sides, or angles that are an integral number of degrees!

If you *absolutely* don't want that for whatever reason, you also need to convert the sides (the `a` and `b` arguments) in `lawOfCosines` to `Double`. That's possible via

```
lawOfCosines aInt bInt gamma = sqrt $ a*a + b*b - 2*a*b*(cos (toRadians gamma)) where
    a = fromInteger aInt
    b = fromInteger bInt
```

Comment: In fact, one might say that, under any reasonable measure, _almost all_ triangles do not have integer sides. (Though the same applies for rational / double, but those at least approximate ℝ properly.)

Answer (score 4):

The type signature for `toRadians` says it takes an `Int` but returns a `Double`. In some programming languages, the conversion from one to the other (but not back) happens automatically. Haskell is not such a language; you must *manually* request conversion, using `fromIntegral`.

The errors you are seeing are all coming from various operations which don't work on `Int`, or from trying to add `Int` to `Double`, or similar. (E.g., `/` doesn't work for `Int`, `pi` doesn't work for `Int`, `sqrt` doesn't work for `Int`...)